# ckeditor change data event broken?

Tags: ckeditor5

When you use ckeditor 5 version 39.0.2 there is an offset of the characters that you are typing.
it doesnt show what you typed entirely, but what you typed before the last character.

As if the last character was never taken care of.

here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pg2777/pa6yke5r/2/

```
 <div>
   <span id='wordcount'>4</span> words
 </div>
 <div id='text'>
    <p>This is some text</p>
 </div>
 <div id="editor">
    <p>       This is some text   </p>
 </div>


    <script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) 
        
        
        
        )
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( editor );
            
            editor.model.document.on( 'change:data', ( evt, data ) => {
            console.log('clic');
     
       $("#text").html($(editor.ui.view.editable.element).html());
        
            } );
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );


    </script>
```

thanks